# Package load failed for ‘rgdal’ in StatET

Tags: r, rgdal, statet

I'm having trouble loading the library `rgdal` in StatET.

```
library(rgdal)

Loading required package: sp
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgdal’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block
```

However, the installation seems valid. When I load the library from a plain R console it works fine:

```
library(rgdal)

Loading required package: sp
rgdal: version: 1.5-18, (SVN revision 1082)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28
Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/share/gdal
GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
Loaded PROJ runtime: Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020, [PJ_VERSION: 631]
Path to PROJ shared files: /usr/share/proj
Linking to sp version:1.4-4
To mute warnings of possible GDAL/OSR exportToProj4() degradation,
use options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none") before loading rgdal.
```

1/ Tried to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. But no love...

2/ Tried to add `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rgdal/libs` as new "Site library" in the R Environment Configuration in Eclipse/StatET. Still no love...

Some system info:

```
R> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 20

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rgdal_1.5-18 sp_1.4-4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3  grid_3.6.3      lattice_0.20-41
```

My linux system:

```
~$ uname -a
Linux darkstar 5.4.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 08:16:25 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: install.packages('rgdal', dependencies=TRUE)

Comment: `rgdal` is installed and working fine from clean console. Problem is inside Eclipse/StatET where the error described appears.

Comment: Did you check RStudio?

Comment: I don't understand. I use StatET for Eclipse. Not RStudio.